# How to create a dropdown filter for all tables within HTML document?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, r-markdown, dt

**Context:**  I have an HTML RMarkdown document that contains about 12 DT (datatables) tables I am looking to create a solution (potentially in Javascript) to have **one** dropdown that filters through **all** the tables within the document.

Here is an example of the document. Within each tab there is DT table. DT tables have filters within each tab which is fine but my stakeholder is asking for one filter to filter through all tables. The filter will be an ID (as a factor) that will be contained within each table.
[image]

Comment: @DaveArmstrong maybe I'm not getting your point but the above is about `library(DT)` not `library(data.table)`. Sure we could filter the `data.frame` or `data.table` under the hood but if you want to programmatically set column filters of a `DataTable` than have a look at `?DT::updateSearch` and it's `keywords` parameter. This however requires a `shiny` context.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong it's not my question, but I agree it needs to be improved (but it's tagged correctly).